# Exclusion script in Marketing Cloud is getting an error

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, exclusion-script

I'm trying to use multiple exclusion scripts in an email activity of a Journey and get this error:

[image]

I've double checked the name of my email fields in my data extensions and they are all "Email" and my DE names are correct as well.  Here's my exclusion script syntax:

(ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Foundation_Staff_DE", "Email", EMAILADDR)) > 0)
OR
(ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Board_Members", "Email", EMAILADDR)) > 0)
OR
(ROWCOUNT(LOOKUPROWS("Employees", "Email", EMAILADDR)) > 0)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you copy paste the exclusion script from a Microsoft Word document or similar?

If you look very carefully, you will find your quotation marks around *Email* being of a different type than standard: `“Email”`, while they should have been `"Email"`.  Very little, but very important difference. It seems to me this is the only issue (at least the most obvious issue) in your exclusion script.

When copy/pasting code - not only from Microsoft Word, I always copy it into a plain text document in a basic text editor, to ensure any special characters are "wiped" from the code.

Comment: Solved!  Thanks!